# Laravel relations and getting them

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my Laravel application I have 3 models (Recipe, Material & Preservation).

Relation between "Recipe" & "Material" has been set as Many To Many.
Also the relation of "Preservation" is both to "Material" & "Recipe", so it has been set as "Polymorphic".

I tested the relations in different calls, and they are working correctly. What I'm looking for here, is a single call that retrieves all data of these there models. Currently I use this call:

> Recipe::with('materials','preservations')->first();

But this won't return the "Preservation"s for materials.

What is the best way to get all data in a single variable with the least queries?

Comment: show the models, this is the way to retrieve all you need, so something, somewhere is wrong.

Comment: @deczo , as I said, the models and their relation are working fine. I tested them. My problem here, is a eloquent query, not a model relation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice what you don't retrieve. All you need is `with('materials.preservations','preservations');` - loads nested relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 'deczo', nested relations can be retrieved like this:

> with('materials.preservations','preservations');

Answer (score 0):

I will explain all the relations in Laravel and show how to get them all:

**in One to One:**
u have to use HasOne on the first model and BelongsTo on the second model

to add record on the first model (HasOne) use the save function

```
$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

to add record on the second model (BelongsTo) use the associate function

```
$user->account()->associate($account);    $user->save();
```

**in One to Many:**
u have to use HasMany on the first model and BelongsTo on the second model

to add record on the first table (HasMany) use the save or saveMany functions

```
$post->comments()->saveMany($comments);
```

to add record on the second model (BelongsTo) use the associate function

```
$user->account()->associate($account);    $user->save();
```

**in Many to Many:**
u have to use BelongsToMany on the first model and BelongsToMany on the second model

to add records on the pivot table use **attach** or **sync** functions:
- both functions accepts single ID or array of ID’s
- the difference is attach checks if the record already exist on the pivot table while sync don’t

**in Polymorphic One to Many:**
u have to use MorphMany on the main model and MorphTo on all the (***able) models

to add records on all the other models use the save

```
$course->tags()->save($tag);
```

the pivot table should have the following columns:
- main model ID
- (***able) ID
- (***able) Type

**in Polymorphic Many to Many:**
u have to use MorphByMany on the main model and MorphToMany on all the (***able) models

to add records on all the other models use the save or saveMany

```
$course->tags()->save($tag);
$course->tags()->saveMany([$tag_1, $tag_2, $tag_3]);
```

the pivot table should have the following columns:
- main model ID
- (***able) ID
- (***able) Type

**in Has Many Through (shortcut):**
u have to use HasManyThrough on the first table and have the normal relations on the other 2 tables

this doesn’t work for ManyToMany relationships (where there’s a pivot table)
however there’s a nice and easy solution for that will be covered somewhere else.